# Wpf Time Traveling in a ComboBox

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a combobox inside my Window.xaml which I initialize with it's property SelectedIndex having the value 0 and with it's property SelectedItem having a Binding to a viewmodel's property.

Sounds pretty easy and basically like this:

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem = "{Binding MyChosenItem}" SelectedIndex="0" ItemsSource={Binding MyList} />
```

Now inside my MyList which is a simple list of string, the first entry is looking like this: "---NULL--". Its just a static entry indicating that user havent selected anything yet.

Once I start my application the combobox sets its SelectedItem to "---NULL---" because of SelectedIndex = 0 and futhermore MyChosenItem gets also set to "---NULL---" since that is the combobox's SelectedItem.

So far so good but now I would like to tearch the combobox to knows that once I have a value in MyChosenItem the combox may not set the selection to "---NULL---".

Here is an example:

If MyChosenItem = null then Combobox shall pick "---NULL---" as standard value though when MyChosenItem = "BMW" the combobox shall pick BMW as selected item which is the 4th item inside the MyList.

How do I do this in WPF? The problem is SelectedIndex which always tries to set the first item as selected item but I need the 4th one. Do I need to time travel to the point after the first item is set and then I set combobox's SelectedItem to 4th one?

Any ideas? Did somebody stumble upon this already in past?

**Edit: I forgot to mention the combobox is a third party control and they somehow set manually SelectedIndex = 0 so I have no chance to change that. Therefore I beg you guys to stick to the requirements give in this question and I hope somebody figures some way to solve this or at least a nice workaround.**

Comment: I'm sorry but this is difficult to answer. You want us to fix a problem caused by a broken third party combobox where we don't have the source? Well lets try: Bind SelectedIndex to a property in your viewmodel, make your checks in the setter, and if the SelectedIndex is wrong, Dispatch a new Raise of get SelectedIndex with the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

First the `SelectedIndex` is 0 based so if you want to select the first item you should use `SelectedIndex=0`.
What normally is done in this situation is initializing `MyChosenItem="---NULL--"` instead of `null` and your `ComboBox` should look like:

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem ="{Binding MyChosenItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
 ItemsSource={Binding MyList}/>
```

You don't need the `SelectedIndex` anymore since your initial `TwoWay Binding` to `MyChosenItem` will update the `SelectedItem` to be "---NULL--".

Comment: Yea I ment the item at position 0. I kind of knew this solution though the problem is that I am using some third party combobox and inside theircode they have SelectedIndex = 0 and they add "---NULL---" to every ItemsSource list entry. I am sorry I should have mentioned this inside my questions. Still I do appreciate your suggestions but could you solve my problem with the requirements given in question please. I wish I could use microsoft combox and solve it this way but its a supid third party control and they did a bunch of shit inside their code. Can you solve it with SelectedIndex?